# Property of the average digits of a number

Tags: calculus, limits

I thought (out of curiosity) about this limit:

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{d(k^n)}{ \lfloor{\log_{10}(k^n)} \rfloor + 1} $$

Where $d(k)$ is the sum of the digits of $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and the $\log$ part is the **length** of the number. Basically, it is the limit of the algebraic average of all the digits in that number.

While this limit does not seem to converge ( checked by a program, not mathematically), it does seem to get bounded after $n>N \in \mathbb{N}$.
I took for example: $k = 12$ and saw that when $n \in [300, 1000] $ the value of the expression is bounded:

$$ 4 \leq \frac{d(k^n)}{ \lfloor{\log_{10}} \rfloor + 1}  \leq 5 $$

(May not be needed, this is my python code):

```
 import math
 def average_digits(n, k):
     return sum( map(int, list(str(n ** k))) ) / (int(math.log10(n ** k)) + 1)
```

When we choose $k= 300$ for example, after some iterations it gets bounded by $0$ and $1$.
Is there a reason for this to happen? Is there a way to estimate the bounds?
Unfortunately I lack this kind of mathematical knowledge, but this is still very mysterious to me.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know remarkably little about the digits of powers. It is conjectured that these digits are uniformly distributed among $0$ to $9$, leading to an estimate of

$$d(k^n)\sim 4.5n\log_{10}k$$

for $10 \nmid k$. This leads to the first "bound" of $12^k$: the value should be around $4.5$. However this is unproven, see http://oeis.org/A001370, for example.

In the case of $k=300$, there are too many zeros in $300^n$. If the conjecture holds true:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {d(300^n)}{\lfloor\log_{10}(300^n)\rfloor+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {d(3^n)}{2n+\lfloor\log_{10}(3^n)\rfloor+1}\sim \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {4.5n\log_{10}3}{2n+n\log_{10}3}=\frac {4.5\log_{10}3}{2+\log_{10}3}$$

which is approximately equal to $0.866750$.

Without the conjecture, the coarse upper bound

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {d(3^n)}{2n+\lfloor\log_{10}(3^n)\rfloor+1}\le \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {9(\lfloor\log_{10}(3^n)\rfloor+1)}{2n+\lfloor\log_{10}(3^n)\rfloor+1}\le \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {9n(\log_{10}3+1)}{2n+n \log_{10}3}=\frac {9\log_{10}3}{2+\log_{10}3}$$

holds, but this value is double that of the previous limit ($1.733500$).

We don't even know if this average is bounded or not. For example for $k=9$, we know that $9 \mid d(9^n)$. However it seems that the question "how many powers of $9$ has digit sum $9m$" is open for $m > 1$, and we only know that they are finite for each $m$ (see http://oeis.org/A056888). This means the the bounds we obtained for the average *could* be broken at any time, however improbable this is (do note that this is different from showing that the limit exists).

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that, what an amazing answer :) Thank you so much!